# Can I visit Singapore from Malaysia and come back soon during my travel itinerary?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, singapore, malaysia

I'm in Kuala Lumpur right now, and have a ticket to go to Ho Chi Minh.

However, I consider visiting Singapore for a few days and then come back to KL. I consider a bus trip.

But I'm fearful of being denied of the re-entry when I come back from Singapore due to the short interval. That would invalidate my travel to HCMC, and I would have to buy a new ticket from Singapore for another place (except Malaysia).

Is it possible to make a short trip to Singapore from Malaysia and then come back?

Comment: What country is your passport? Malaysia and Singapore have different relationships with different countries. Here's a list of countries who need visas to enter Singapore: https://www.ica.gov.sg/services_centre_overview.aspx?pageid=252&secid=165/www.ica.gov.sg/services_centre_overview.aspx?pageid=252&secid=165

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, this is not only possible but quite common: Malaysia and Singapore have a land (well, bridge) border and many people do day trips in both directions.  I've gone from Singapore to JB and back in an evening a few times just to eat dinner!

If you have a ticket out of Malaysia, and don't have a history of visa runs, I see no reason why Malaysia would deny you entry.

Comment: To add to that, since I had friends in Malaysia, I used to go every two weeks from Singapore. Malaysian immigration was very welcoming to me and didn't even ask for proof of stay or return ticket.